# Finding a formula for $(1^3)\cdot(n)+(2^3)\cdot(n-1)+(3^3)\cdot(n-2)+ \cdots + (n^3)\cdot(1)$

Tags: summation, gauss-sums

> I need a formula for this sum:
>   $$(1^3)\cdot(n)+(2^3)\cdot(n-1)+(3^3)\cdot(n-2)+ \cdots + (n^3)\cdot(1)$$

I have found this formula :
$$1\cdot n +2\cdot(n-1)+3\cdot(n-2)+ \cdots +(n-1)\cdot 2 +n\cdot1= \frac16n(n+1)(n+2)$$
but it is not exactly what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your sum is $\sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^3(n+1-k)$, which is $(n+1)\sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^3 - \sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^4$. Now have a look at the sums listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#From_examples_to_matrix_theorem.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth i understand what you're saying but i still need further explanations:))

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can be useful to [find closed forms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%5E3+%28n+-+k+%2B+1%29%2C+k%3D1+to+n) which can be then proven after you know what it is.

Comment: Are you from Braşov? Buildings on your picture look familiar to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use generating functions.

Write your sum as:

$\begin{align*}
   S_{n + 1}
     &= \sum_{0 \le k \le n + 1} k^3 (n + 1 - k)
\end{align*}$

So this is a convolution. It is the coefficients of the series:

$\begin{align*}
   S(z)
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} S_n z^n \\
     &= \left( \sum_{k \ge 0} k^3 z^k \right)
          \cdot \left( \sum_{k \ge 0} k z^k \right) \\
     &= \frac{z (1 + 4 z + z^2)}{(1 - z)^4}
          \cdot \frac{z}{(1 - z)^2} \\
     &= \frac{z^2 (1 + 4 z + z^2)}{(1 - z)^6}
\end{align*}$

Extract coefficients, using the generalized binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 + u)^{-m}
     &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} u^k \\
     &= \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} u^k
\end{align*}$

giving:

$\begin{align*}
  S_n
    &= [z^n] \frac{z^2 (1 + 4 z + z^2)}{(1 - z)^6} \\
    &= ([z^{n - 2}] + 4 [z^{n - 3}] + [z^{n - 4}]) (1 - z)^{-6} \\
    &= \binom{n - 2 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1}
          + 4 \binom{n - 3 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1}
          + \binom{n - 4 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} \\
    &= \frac{3 n^5 - 5 n^3 + 2 n}{60}
\end{align*}$

Your sum is:

$\begin{align*}
  S_{n + 1}
    &= \frac{3 n^5 + 15 n^4 + 25 n^3 + 15 n^2 + 2 n}{60} \\
    &= \frac{n (n + 1) (n + 2) (3 n^2 + 6 n + 1)}{60}
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 0):

I can rewrite the sum as $S_n=\sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^3(n+1-k)=(n+1)\sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^3 - \sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^4$. Now, we can show by induction that $A_n=\sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^3=\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}$ and $B_n=\sum\limits _{k=1}^{n}k^4=\frac{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}{30}$. Substituing this formulas in: $S_n=(n+1)A_n - B_n$, I have: $$S_n=(n+1)\cdot \frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}-\frac{6n^5+15n^4+10n^3-n}{30}=\frac{3n^5+15n^4+25n^3+15n^2+2n}{60}$$
This is the expansion of your sum.

Comment: Your expression for $A_n$ is confusing because you include $n+1$, but then you use it again when taking the difference vs. $B_n$...

Comment: Sorry, my error. Edited and corrected.

Comment: This doesn't agree with the result from [WolframAlpha](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332802/finding-a-formula-for-13-cdotn23-cdotn-133-cdotn-2-cdots#3332817)

Comment: Now, it's correct.

Comment: THANK YOU MAN <3